# how to see a checkbox is not checked

Tags: php, html, forms, function, checkbox

I want to alert user if they haven't checked any checkbox, and return to the form
After they checked at least one checkbox, proceed into the next page
How can I do that ?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="
    <?php 
    echo $DateArr[$record_count].";";
    echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";";
    echo $TotalArr[$record_count].";";
    echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
    ?>
    " onClick="checkTotal()"/>

<td ALIGN="right" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" onMouseOver="CheckBoxStatus()"></td>
```

**javascript :**

```
function CheckBoxStatus()
                      {

                        var checkbox_status = document.getElementsByName("pay[]").value;                            
                            if (checkbox_status = ";;;")
                            {
                               alert("Please select at least one to proceed!");
                               return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              alert("Continue!");
                              return true;
                            }


                      }
```

If user hasn't checked, at least one checkbox, alert the message and return to form

Then

```
<form name="payform"  method="POST" action="payment.php"  onSubmit=" CheckBoxStatus()">
```

How can I stay in the form if user is not checking any checkboxes ?

May be like this :

```
function CheckBoxStatus()
                          {
                                if (document.getElementsByName("pay[]").checked == true) 
                                {
                                    document.forms["payform"].submit(); 
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert("Please select at least one invoice to proceed!");
                                   document.forms["payform"].reset();   
                                   return false;

                                }
                          }
```

can i do like this :
`

```
function CheckBoxStatus()
                          {
                            var status=$("pay[]").attr('checked');

                            if (status=true)
                            {
                             //if(document.getElementsByName("pay[]").checked) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Please select at least one to proceed!");
                                return false;
                            }


                          }`
```

Comment: The checkbox will always have a value in JS, the way you're generating it. You want to check the checkboxe's `.checked` attribute, which is true/false.

Comment: if checkbox.value = ";;;" = false ?

Comment: no. `if (checkbox.checked == false) { ... it's not checked ...}`.

Comment: `if(document.getElementsByName("pay[]").checked == false) {
         return true;
        }
        else {
         alert("Please select at least one to proceed!");
         return false;`
        }

Comment: getElementsByName returns an array of matching nodes... you really need to read up on DOM operations...

Comment: @Marc B : How can I do that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6747/discussion-between-rick-ant-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
var $checked = $("input:checked");
if($checked.length == 0) {
     alert("Please select at least one to proceed!");
}
```

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: where should I put that function ? at CheckBoxStatus() ?

Comment: jQuery isn't necessary if this is all he's using it for.

Comment: still continue into the next page, even there's no checkbox being checked...??

Comment: how can I make it stay in the form until at least one checkbox's being checked ?

Answer (score 0):

That HTML is a bit of a mess. A couple of things...

1. Get rid of the `<td>` tag containing the button. It doesn't look like it has a purpose.
2. To call the JavaScript you need to use `onsubmit` not `onMouseOver`.
3. To check if the checkbox is checked change your function to the following.

   ```
   function checkBoxStatus { 
       if(document.getElementsByName("pay[]").checked) {
           return true;
       }
       else {
           alert("Please select at least one to proceed!");
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

EDIT; forgot the alert

Comment: where should I call this function ? on the button or at the form ? <form name="payform" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes_abel();" method="POST" action="payment.php"  onSubmit="CheckBoxStatus()">

Comment: Either on the form or the submit button. You already have an `onsubmit` on the form, so perhaps combine them?

Comment: when it returns false, why is it stil continuing into the next page ??

Comment: how can I stay in the same page if user is not checking any checkboxes ?

Comment: If I click one of the checkbox, it still gives me "Please select at least one to proceed !"

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have included jquery. :|
2. Try this:

   ```
   <input id="ipay" type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="
   <?php 
   echo $DateArr[$record_count].";";
   echo $invoiceArr[$record_count].";";
   echo $TotalArr[$record_count].";";
   echo $amount_dueArr[$record_count];
   ?>"
   />

   <td ALIGN="right" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue"></td>
   <form id="pform" name="payform"  method="POST" action="payment.php">
   ```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pform').submit(function(e) {
                    var paycheck = $('#ipay').attr('checked');
                    if(paycheck != true or paycheck != 'checked') {
                            alert('Please check at least one option.');
                            e.preventDefault();
                    }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Verify Checkbox</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function verifyCheckboxSelected(form) {
                var theForm = document.forms[form];
                var valid = false;

                for( var i=0; i < theForm.length; i++ ) { 
                    if(theForm.elements[i].checked) {
                        valid = true;
                    } 
                }

                if (!valid) {
                    alert('You must select at least one checkbox')
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" onSubmit="return verifyCheckboxSelected(this.name)">
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]"/>Checkbox A</br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]"/>Checkbox B</br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBoxes[]"/>Checkbox C</br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```